# MySQL - update whole column with records from parent table?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables `t1`, `t2` that I have created and loaded data from a CSV into these.

I had to then create a new PK column as the existing columns (`t1.old_id`, `t2.old_id`) are strings that would naturally be a PK are not absolutely fixed (this seems to be advised against?)
so I created a `id PK INT AUTO_INCREMENT` in each table

as one record in `t1` is linked to many in `t2` and I want to maintain referential integrity between these two tables.

I believe what i need to do is create an `id INT NOT NULL` in `t2` as an FK

This `t2.id is blank at the moment (as it is dependent on`t1.id`)

Am I right in thinking I need an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN` of some description to make this work?

The following produces the data exactly that I want to update into my `t2.id` column - but I don't know how to do the update

```
select t1.id
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.old_id = t2.old_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated `UPDATE` query like this

```
UPDATE t2
SET id = (SELECT MAX(t1.id) FROM t1 WHERE t1.old_id = t2.old_id);
```

*Assuming you have a single `t1.id` for each `t1.old_id`

*On a Separate Note, You should name `t2.id` like `t2.t1ID` so as to remove ambiguity if and when you have a identity column in `t2` as well named `id`*

Comment: Thank you for the additional info, i had t1_id but didnt type it in my question, but hints like this are very welcome (started SQL this week)..i ended up at this on my own some how just before seeing your response, not really sure how!

Comment: ive marked this as correct as it is the solution i came to, but the other works just as well and is shorter!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join in your `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE t2 
    JOIN t1 ON t1.old_id = t2.old_id
SET t2.id = t1.id
```